# How can I breakup my large Backbone.js project into sections?

Tags: backbone.js

I have 1 controller with hundreds of routes.  Is there a system to break up an app into sections and only load the javascript files needed for that section?

Otherwise the user might have to download all the javascript for the entire app from the first load.

Seems like on certain controller hits, it should detect if a new download of javascript is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using asset packager such as [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit) that will minify your multiple scripts into one compressed one on demand.

This way you can structure your scripts however makes more sense to you, break them into as many files you wish, and the asset handle will take care of compressing and combining them.
If some scripts are way too big to be loaded everywhere, you can always move loading of bigger scripts into views that need these scripts using **content_for**

For instance:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= include_javascripts :my_big_files %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Jammit can't even shake a stick at the asset pipeline these days.

Answer (score 5):

You could look into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Just remember that loading modules dynamically has it's downsides as well:

- Application is less responsive, each time you load new module user has to wait.
- Code can get more complex as you can only execute certain parts only once something has been loaded.
- And some more complex problems in specific applications.

Ideally you want to keep your module/multiple file approach, but for deployment merge everything in one file. Even if it's a huge file it will still load faster than say 50 files and be more pleasant for user than having to see loading screen each time he navigates to different part of the application.

I think [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) offer both things, you can load things on the go when you develop, but when you're ready for deployment you still can package all in one file.

Comment: RequireJS has an optimization tool which does exactly what you suggest. Also, though the documentation is a bit quiet on this, it lets you use syntax like `var CoreModels = require('models/core');` inside each define(), so you get Python-style imports in Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you could be Stitch. It is a part of the node eco system, and can compile coffeescript on the fly.

https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch